# How to invoke an overloaded parent cout friend class from a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, inheritance

Imagine a setup as follows. How do I invoke the base class `cout` from within the derived class `cout`? I could use the `getBrand()` method, but I feel like I should be able to directly access the base class' `cout` friend function.

I hacked a bit, and tried `this.Brand` and also just `Brand`. No luck.

```
class Brand {
public:
    Brand(std::string brand):brand_(brand) {};
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Brand & b) {
        out << b.brand_ << ' ';
        return out;
    }   
    std::string getBrand()const { return brand_; }     
private:
    std::string brand_;
}

class Cheese : public Brand {
public:
    Cheese(std::string brand, std::string type):Brand(brand), type_(type) {};
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Cheese & c) {
        out << /* THIS.BRAND?! BRAND?! getBrand() meh.. */ << ' ' << c.type_ << std::endl; // <-- HERE
        return out;
    }
private:
    std::string type_;
}

int main() {
    Cheese c("Cabot Clothbound", "Cheddar");
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Cabot Clothbound Cheddar
```

Comment: How should the output be `Cabot Clothbound Cheddar` when `Brand`'s `operator<<` puts trailing newline into the stream?

Comment: Good point, but beside the point. Edited and removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could invoke the overloaded `operator <<` of the Base class from the derived class. Since, you declared the operator as a friend, you could simply cast the the derived class to a base class:

```
class Cheese : public Brand {
public:
    Cheese(std::string brand, std::string type):Brand(brand), type_(type) {};
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Cheese & c) {

        //ADDED
        out << static_cast<const Brand&>(c) << c.type_ << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
private:
    std::string type_;
};
```

Output:

```
Cabot Clothbound Cheddar
```

[**See it Live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f15401d949a1e294)

Comment: 1 minute faster than you, but you got a live demo, while I don't have one, so take my upvote. =)

Answer (score 2):

Cast it, like this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Cheese& c)
{
    out << static_cast<const Brand &>(c);
    out << c.type_ << std::endl;

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are responding correctly to your specific question, but whenever you'll try to use polymorphism like this:

```
Brand const &c = Cheese("Cabot Clothbound", "Cheddar");
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

`operator <<` corresponding to `Brand` will be called instead of `Cheese`'s.

The good way to do it is to use a virtual *print* member function:

```
class Brand {
public:
    Brand(std::string const & brand):brand_(brand) {}
    virtual ~Brand() {}
    virtual void print(std::ostream & out) const {
        out << brand_;   
    }
    std::string const & getBrand()const { return brand_; }     
private:
    std::string brand_;
};
```

```
class Cheese : public Brand {
public:
    Cheese(std::string const & brand, std::string const & type):Brand(brand), type_(type) {}
    void print(std::ostream & out) const override {
        Brand::print(out); // calling base print()
        out << ' ' << type_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string type_;
};
```

Then, you only need a single `operator <<` for the base class which will call your `print` virtual member function:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Brand & b) {
    b.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da2439e81e5e5616)

Comment: Excellent response; thank you for this. Despite the fact that it doesn't answer the question as directly as the above, I was sorely tempted to accept this as the answer. Regardless, thank you for taking the time to teach me this, I appreciate it. :^)

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't do anything like `Brand::operator<<`, because both `operator<<` are defined as `friend` and thus they are not member functions.

If you want to invoke `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Brand&)`, you just have to pass correct types to that, and since Derived classes can be easily casted to Base classes, you can just do

```
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Cheese & c) {
    out << static_cast<const Brand&>(c) << ' ' << c.type_ << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```